# Updating API response to GET request with node js express

Tags: node.js

I am a web development noob. I am building a web app in node js express, and I am able to populate a route with a dummy json. I don't want to use a database but just have live data being updated every few seconds.

```
app.route('/robot-data').get( async (req, res) => {
    res.json([ // dummy data
        {"data":0},
    ]);
});
```

My html is able to read from this API fine. The problem is, I would like to update the response, eventually with an emit event but for testing I am trying to just do it periodically.

```
let dataSource = 0;
const updateDataSource = () => {
  const delta = Math.random();
  dataSource += delta;
  app.get('/robot-data', (req, res) => {
      res.json([
        // updated data
      ]);
    });
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, _ => {
    setInterval(()=> updateDataSource(), 3000);
});
```

However, when I run this the json at the endpoint doesn't change when I refresh. Basically, I want to have what is happening at this api for my json. https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544

I've looked into websockets etc but I really just want to do what the ISS api is doing.

Comment: your example would actually work if you wait 3 seconds between refreshes. Just add the actual data there :
res.json([
       {"data": dataSource}
      ]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code executes the statement `app.get('/robot-data', (req, res) => {...})` repeatedly, which does not work. [Middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) functions like `(req, res) => {...}` must be set up only *once*, and if their behaviour shall change over time, they can refer to variables defined outside of them, and these variables can change.

In your case, this would look so:

```js
let dataSource = 0;
const updateDataSource = () => {
  const delta = Math.random();
  dataSource += delta;
};
app.get('/robot-data', (req, res) => {
  res.json([
    {"data":dataSource}
  ]);
});
```

Comment: I wanted to suggest the same ( to move the app.get statement outside the updateDataSource function ) but it actually works as is too. I think, maybe the OP just forgot to actually output the data source

Comment: Didn't forget, I truly am a noob so I just did it wrong. I understand now! Thanks so much.